# Ideals of Dedekind rings are projective

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, dedekind-domain

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Show that $I$ is a projective $R$-module.

My definition of a projective module is that it is a direct summand of a free module, i.e. there exists an $R$ - module $S$ such that $I \oplus S$ is free. Since $R$ is Dedekind I could take $I^{-1}$ to be the inverse of $I$ and guess that $I \oplus I^{-1}$ is free. I am pretty sure that $I \oplus I^{-1} \neq R$ in the general case, so maybe my guess of $I^{-1}$ beeing the direct summand is wrong.

Comment: In general, $I^{-1}$ is not contained in $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$I$ is finitely generated, and for every  prime ideal $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}R$, the localisation $I_\mathfrak{p}$ is a free $R_\mathfrak{p}$-module of rank 1$.

Comment: I think I know how to proof the proposition if I assume your statement. But I don't see why $I_p$ is a free $R_p$-module.

Comment: What do you know about localisations of Dedekind domains?

Comment: I know that the localisation $R_p$ is a valuation ring and hence a local ring. Is $I_p$ and ideal of $R_p$?

Comment: Yes, it is an ideal of $R_\mathfrak{p}$. It is a *discrete* valuation domain, hence it is a (local) P.I.D.

Comment: Hm. I have not seen a proof that it is a discrete valuation ring. Is that hard to show?

Comment: In a valuation domain, finitely generated ideals are principal, and a Dedekind domain is noetherian. Is that enough for you?

Comment: Yes I get it now. Thank you